# Обращение к группе методов класса без присвоения экземпляра

Tags: php

Понимаю, что вопрос звучит несколько страшно, но все же... Более на примере

Имеется класс

```
class some
{
    function first($data)
    {
        return $data;
    }

    function second($data)
    {
        return $data;
    }

    function third($data)
    {
        return $data;
    }        
}

$some = new some;
```

Возможно ли обратиться к группе методов, используя экземпляр только единожды, чтобы

```
$some->first("hello "), $some->second("my "), $some->third("world");
```

имело вид и работало как

```
$some->first("hello ")->second("my ")->third("world");
```

З.Ы. Прошу простить за отступы от теории и т.п. И ограничиться широкими дискуссиями... Напишите краткий ответ типа: нет потому что, или да, но для этого нужно то-то!

Спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно, тогда метод должен возвращать:

```
return $this;
```

То-есть, тот же самый экземпляр.

Comment: работает, но при условии что внутри метода присутствует конструкция `echo`. Подальшее решение уже найду. Спасибо!

Comment: Не могу представить как `echo` может влиять на ситуацию.

Суть в том, что в цепочке:

    $some->first("hello ")->second("my ")->third("world");

метод `first()` вызывается напрямую из объекта $some, а метод `second()` вызывается уже из результата, который вернул `first()`. Поэтому важно чтобы `first()` возвращал `$this`. Тоже самое и для `second()` по отношению к `third()`. Соответственно, если нужно чтобы все методы сработали независимо от перестановки в цепочке, то все они должны возвращать ссылку на объект `$this`.

Comment: все они и должны возвращать `$this` по основной задумке... но без `echo` вызов отдает `Object id #3`. Может я просто запутался, нужно отдохнуть) на главный вопрос я ответ получил) спасибо.